# Receive a duplicate message from the socket on the user side !! . ( SignalR )

Tags: reactjs, sockets, asp.net-core, signalr

The problem is that when a message is sent through the server and socket method to users connected to the relevant socket, on the client side when the message is received, how many times this message is repeated, what do you think is the problem ?

I use the following packages :

ASP Core 5 : SignalR | ReactJS : @microsoft / signalr

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, but I do not know how correct it is and it does not cause a problem, now that it works .

[image]